# Enable domain users on network to edit mediawiki page

Tags: mediawiki

Is there a way to allow domain users to edit a mediawiki page? (without manually creating multiple users?)

Answer (score 1):

You could try to install [the LDAP Extension](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:LDAP_Authentication) and diallow all edits for anonymous users and disable manual registration:

```
$wgGroupPermissions['*']['edit'] = false;
$wgGroupPermissions['*']['createaccount'] = true;
```

So, only your ldap members can login and edit pages.